# Hierarchical group sizes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a Multi-Index dataframe in Pandas with multiple levels like the following:

```
                     A         B         C
X      Y     Z                          
bar   one    a   -0.007381 -0.365315 -0.024817
             b   -1.219794  0.370955 -0.795125
baz   three  a    0.145578  1.428502 -0.408384
             b   -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      two    a   -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      four   a    0.21     -0.967123  1.202234
foo   one    b   -1.046479 -1.250595  0.781722
             a    1.314373  0.333150  0.133331
qux   one    c    0.716789  0.616471 -0.298493
      two    b    0.385795 -0.915417 -1.367644
```

I would like to know:

1. The leaf size **for each value for each level**. In the example above this would be:

   > ```
   > bar: 2
   > bar & one: 2
   > bar & one & a: 1
   > bar & one & b: 1
   > baz: 4
   > baz & three: 2
   > baz & three & a: 1
   > baz & three & b: 1 
   > etc.
   > ```
2. The relative size between consecutive levels. In the example above this would be:

   > ```
   > # First level -> Second level :
   > bar: 1 (i.e. grouping ["one"])
   > baz: 3 (i.e. grouping ["three", two", "four"])
   > foo: 1 (i.e. grouping ["one"])
   > qux: 2 (i.e. grouping ["one", "two"])
   >
   > # Second level -> Third level
   > ... 
   >
   > # Third level -> Fourth level (if we had one)
   > etc.
   > ```

Is there any way to do this in Pandas, and (preferably) get the result in a dataframe as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you added a another part I will flesh out my answer. To do part 1 I would use a list comprehension to loop the different groupby levels and get the size of all the groups. Then `concat` together the resulting dataframes from each groupby:

```
print pd.concat([df.groupby(level=x).size() for x in [0,[0,1],[0,1,2]]])

bar                2
baz                4
foo                2
qux                2
(bar, one)         2
(baz, four)        1
(baz, three)       2
(baz, two)         1
(foo, one)         2
(qux, one)         1
(qux, two)         1
(bar, one, a)      1
(bar, one, b)      1
(baz, four, a)     1
(baz, three, a)    1
(baz, three, b)    1
(baz, two, a)      1
(foo, one, a)      1
(foo, one, b)      1
(qux, one, c)      1
(qux, two, b)      1
```

Part 2 is more complicated but I think we can use the same structure. Probably many ways to do it, but I will use the ngroups method within that same basic list comprehension:

```
def group_count(df,x):
    by = df['A'].groupby(level=x[0])
    return by.agg(lambda g: g.groupby(level=x[1]).ngroups)

lvl = [0,[0,1],[0,1,2]]
print pd.concat([group_count(df,x) for x in zip(lvl[:-1],lvl[1:])])

bar             1
baz             3
foo             1
qux             2
(bar, one)      2
(baz, four)     1
(baz, three)    2
(baz, two)      1
(foo, one)      2
(qux, one)      1
(qux, two)      1
```

Of course you may not like the index as tuples; you could reset the index within the list comprehension to get the following if you prefer (for example, this if for part 1):

```
lvl = [0,[0,1],[0,1,2]]
print pd.concat([df.groupby(level=x).size().reset_index() for x in lvl])

   0    X      Y    Z
0  2  bar    NaN  NaN
1  4  baz    NaN  NaN
2  2  foo    NaN  NaN
3  2  qux    NaN  NaN
0  2  bar    one  NaN
1  1  baz   four  NaN
2  2  baz  three  NaN
3  1  baz    two  NaN
4  2  foo    one  NaN
5  1  qux    one  NaN
6  1  qux    two  NaN
0  1  bar    one    a
1  1  bar    one    b
2  1  baz   four    a
3  1  baz  three    a
4  1  baz  three    b
5  1  baz    two    a
6  1  foo    one    a
7  1  foo    one    b
8  1  qux    one    c
9  1  qux    two    b
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more direct method, but this would do by getting the value of the index:

```
In [50]:

df.index.tolist()
Out[50]:
[('bar', 'one', 'a'),
 ('bar', 'one', 'b'),
 ('baz', 'three', 'a'),
 ('baz', 'three', 'b'),
 ('baz', 'two', 'a'),
 ('baz', 'four', 'a'),
 ('foo', 'one', 'b'),
 ('foo', 'one', 'a'),
 ('qux', 'one', 'c'),
 ('qux', 'two', 'b')]
In [53]:

len([item for item in df.index.tolist() if item[0]=='bar'])
Out[53]:
2
In [54]:

len([item for item in df.index.tolist() if (item[0]=='bar')&(item[1]=='one')])
Out[54]:
2
```

Or vectorized:

```
In [71]:

A=np.asanyarray(df.index.tolist())
In [72]:

(A[:,:2]==np.array(['bar', 'one'])).all(1).sum()
Out[72]:
2
In [73]:

(A[:,:3]==np.array(['baz','three','b'])).all(1).sum()
Out[73]:
1
```

Comment: I was thinking a list comprehension too, but do it over the the groupby levels: `pd.concat([df.groupby(level=x).size() for x in [0,[0,1],[0,1,2]]])`. So kind of a variation on you first answer.

Comment: @KarlD., Nice one liner solution! With more levels list comprehensions will get quite verbose. The vectorization looks a little better, as only the length of the query (either 2 or 3 in this case) need to be specified.

Comment: Thanks @KarlD and CT Zhu.I have updated the OP since I realize that that I am looking for **two** types of size measures.